# Запрос на Update

Tags: mysql, sql, update

Имеется две таблицы:`games (id, name, devices)` и `groped_games (id, game_id, group_name)`. В `games.devices` может храниться значение `desktop` или `mobile`.
Как хранятся игры в games:

```
1    loto     desktop
2    loto     mobile
3    soccer   desktop
4    soccer   mobile
```

Нужно заменить `groped_games.dame_id`, где соответствующая `games.devices = 'mobile'` на `id` игры с таким же названием, но где `games.devices = 'desktop'`.
Я начал писать запрос, но что-то зашёл в тупик:

```
UPDATE
  grouped_games
SET
  games_id = (SELECT games_id FROM games WHERE #тут тупик)
```

Answer (score 0):

Постановка вопроса так себе. Если я правильно понял то

```
update  
gg
set game_id = g.id from
groped_games  gg
join  games g on g.id=gg.id
```

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, получится нечто вроде

```
update games t1, games t2, groped_games t3
set t3.game_id := t1.id
where t1.name = t2.name
  and t1.devices = 'desktop'
  and t2.devices = 'mobile'
  and t2.id = t3.game_id
```